# Synchronizer token pattern: How does it prevent combination of XSS and CSRF?

Tags: security, xss, csrf, owasp

I have been looking into the OWASP recommendation to prevent CSRF attacks (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Now, what I do not understand is how this would prevent an attack that is a combination of an XSS and a CSRF attack. Let's say we have the following attack scenario:

---

1. Attacker is able to perform a stored XSS attack, so that the script that the attacker inserts on the website is executed everytime a user visits the page.
2. This script will completely redesign the DOM, for example instead of the original form where a user needs to give some irrelevant information, the attacker's script redesigns it so that this form will be redesigned to a form where a user with admin privileges is added. Note that the user will not see this, as the labels of the fields will remain the same. Only the POST will be different.
3. The attacker knows that this website uses anti-CSRF tokens. Looking at the OWASP recommendation: '(..)application should include a hidden input parameter with a common name such as "CSRFToken"', the attacker knows that most websites will have a hidden field with this id somewhere on the page.
4. the attacker makes sure the value of this field is also submitted in the fake POST. Even though the attacker doesn't know the value of this hidden field, it can specify in the POST that this value should be sent with the request. This is possible, as the user's DOM has been modified, the request will come from the user's browser, the user's cookies will also be sent with the request.
5. The user submits the form, and the fake user is created.

---

It seems to me this cannot be prevented by just using a CSRF token. Or is an implicit assumption of the synchronizer pattern that XSS attacks have been neutralized?

Comment: Isnt that specifically mentioned in the OWASP article under 5. No Cross Site Scripting vulns?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I missed that section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is an implicit assumption of the synchronizer pattern that XSS attacks have been neutralized?

Yes. If your website is attacked in this way then it is an XSS attack rather than CSRF. CSRF simply means the request is made "cross site", whereas in your example the request is on the same site - it is just the scripting that is "cross site".